# Covariance of Ito Integrals

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am new to stochastic calculus and I'm still grappling with the concepts. Can someone please verify whether I am correct to solve my question this way:

In my question, I need to calculate:

\begin{equation}
E \left [ \int^c_atdW_t \cdot \int^d_b tdW_t \right ]
\end{equation}

where $0 < a < b < c < d$ and where $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion.

My intuition is that the non-overlapping regions in the integral are independent, which then get evaluated to zero, and therefore the expected value becomes:

\begin{equation}
E \left [ \int^c_btdW_t \cdot \int^c_b tdW_t \right ]
\end{equation}

and so by Ito Isometry, I get:

\begin{equation}
 \int^c_bt^2dt = \frac{c^3 - b^3}{3}
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: The Brownian differences are independent, not the Brownian bits themselves.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. "...non-overlapping regions in the integral are independent..." is more than you need (it does hold here because the integrands are deterministic). By the martingale property of Ito integral with respect to Brownian filtration, the same result would hold for general Ito integrands.